# Error: Undefined variable in controller as syntax in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am creating my portfolio using AngularJS. I hav created a projects.json file for all my projects. I want a modal to open when I click a specific project button. So I created a function that will take id as an argument and find a project based on that id. But it is giving me error of undefined.

### # PROJECT CONTROLLER #

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular.module('myPortfolio')
        .controller('ProjectCtrl', function($scope, projectFactory, $state) {

            var projectCtrl = this;
            projectCtrl.projects;           

            projectFactory.getProjects().then(function(projects) {
                projectCtrl.projects = projects.data;
                console.log(projectCtrl.projects);
            });

            projectCtrl.openProject = openProject();

            function openProject(id) {
                for (var i = 0; i < projectCtrl.projects.length; i++) {
                    if (projectCtrl.projects[i].id === id) {
                        projectCtrl.project = projectCtrl.projects[i];
                    }
                }
                console.log(projectCtrl.project);
            };
        });
})()
```

### #PROJECT FACTORY#

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular.module('myPortfolio')
        .factory('projectFactory', function($http) {

            function getProjects() {
                return $http.get('components/data/projects.json');
            }

            return {
                getProjects : getProjects
            }
        });
})();
```

### #ERRORS#

```
angular.js:13550 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at openProject (projects.controller.js:18)
    at new <anonymous> (projects.controller.js:15)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4665)
    at R.instance (angular.js:10115)
    at n (angular.js:9033)
    at g (angular.js:8397)
    at g (angular.js:8400)
    at angular.js:8277
    at angular.js:1751
    at n.$eval (angular.js:17229)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13550(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10225n.$apply @ angular.js:17334(anonymous function) @ angular.js:1749invoke @ angular.js:4665c @ angular.js:1747yc @ angular.js:1767ee @ angular.js:1652(anonymous function) @ angular.js:30863b @ angular.js:3166Qf @ angular.js:3456Pf.d @ angular.js:3444

projects.controller.js:13 [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use `projectCtrl.projects` before it's been populated in `then` callback.

Looks like you don't want to call `openProject()` but instead you are trying to set up a reference as `projectCtrl.openProject`.

You should do something like this:

```
angular.module('myPortfolio')
    .controller('ProjectCtrl', function($scope, projectFactory, $state) {

        var projectCtrl = this;    

        projectFactory.getProjects().then(function(projects) {
            projectCtrl.projects = projects.data;
        });

        projectCtrl.openProject = openProject; // don't add () after function name

        function openProject(id) {
            for (var i = 0; i < projectCtrl.projects.length; i++) {
                if (projectCtrl.projects[i].id === id) {
                    projectCtrl.project = projectCtrl.projects[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
            console.log(projectCtrl.project);
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`projectCtrl.openProject = openProject();` is missing the `id` param. Also, the error is telling you that `projectCtrl.projects;` is undefined. A good practice would be to initalize it such that `projectCtrl.projects = [];` so that you can continue troubleshooting what the true issue is.